# Table canot be formatted to my ideal shape

Tags: python, pandas

Table canot be formatted to my ideal shape.I wrote codes,

```
#coding:utf-8
import scipy as sp
import scipy.stats
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = df.loc[:, :].tolist()
ans = sp.stats.kruskal(data)
```

df variable has data like

```
10min 20min 30min 40min 50min 60min
0      6    7    9   15   21   30
0      2    4    7   9    13   24
0      3    9    18  25   34   49
0      7    13   17  21   25   28
```

When I run this codes,

```
data = df.loc[:, :].tolist()
```

I get this error,

```
File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3614, in __getattr__  
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)  
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist'
```

I want to reshape df into

```
 [[6,7,9,15,21,30],[2,4,7,9,13,24],[3,9,18,25,34,49],[7,13,17,21,25,28]]
```

to be able to be used in `sp.stats.kruskal method`.
How should I fix this?What is wrong in my codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `df.values` which is Numpy representation of NDFrame. See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) for details.

```
>>> df.values.tolist()
[[6L, 7L, 9L, 15L, 21L, 30L], [2L, 4L, 7L, 9L, 13L, 24L], [3L, 9L, 18L, 25L, 34L, 49L], [7L, 13L, 17L, 21L, 25L, 28L]]
```

While this does arranges Df values to list of list, it does not solve for kruskal.

You may want to investigate that further.

```
>>> data = df.values.tolist()
>>> sp.stats.kruskal(data)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    sp.stats.kruskal(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 5030, in kruskal
    raise ValueError("Need at least two groups in stats.kruskal()")
ValueError: Need at least two groups in stats.kruskal()
```

**EDIT**

May be you are looking for following which is achived by passing *arg directly to krushkal's function.

```
>>> args = [df[col] for col in df.columns]
>>> args
[0    6
0    2
0    3
0    7
Name: 10min, dtype: int64, 0     7
0     4
0     9
0    13
Name: 20min, dtype: int64, 0     9
0     7
0    18
0    17
Name: 30min, dtype: int64, 0    15
0     9
0    25
0    21
Name: 40min, dtype: int64, 0    21
0    13
0    34
0    25
Name: 50min, dtype: int64, 0    30
0    24
0    49
0    28
Name: 60min, dtype: int64]
>>> sp.stats.kruskal(*args)
KruskalResult(statistic=17.757426823940584, pvalue=0.003266295595505132)
>>>
```